# Encontrar banco de imagens para opencv

Tags: processamento-de-imagens

Existe algum site que possua bancos de imagens de cenas naturais para aplicações de processamento de imagens que possa ser utilizado no *opencv*?

Comment: Olá. Bem vindo ao SOpt. Por favor, faça o [tour] e leia a [help]. Este site não é um fórum, então perguntas para sugestão de conteúdo não são muito bem aceitas. De todas as formas, além de fora do escopo, ela é muito ampla. Que tipo de problema você tem? Qualquer imagem de cenas naturais serve? Qual é a relação com o OpenCV? Afinal, se qualquer imagem de "cenas naturais" servir, o Google Images é a melhor resposta pra você.